# Creation of new process for each request of web page?

Tags: php, process, pid

It might be a basic question but everytime a user call a php file from a server, does it create a new process from that server ?

For example, I have a basic form (let's say on index.php) that submits a text to another php file.
In that php file, I print the **posix_getpid()**.

I opened in two tabs my index.php an filled in and submitted a text and I ended up with
two different pid on each tab.

Which lead me to the conclusion that a server probably create a new process for each script.
Am I right ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you're running apache as your web server.

When a request comes in, apache starts a new thread. PHP is then invoked on this new thread, hence why you get a new process id every time.

This is, of course, greatly simplified.

I recommend reading [this](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2008/11/how-does-php-echos-a-hello-world-behind-the-scene/) article for a deeper understanding.

Edit: It seems that the process differs between platforms. It works the way I described above on Windows, but multiple apache processes are executed on Unix.

Comment: Ok, so it is because of apache. But your explanation is a bit weird to me because thread and processes are fairly different. I mean, if apache starts a new thread, that means that every php script should have apache pid !

Comment: No, the PID comes from the newly created PHP instance, not the apache process.

Comment: Just to see if I get this straight, every time a php script is called, apache create a new process to handle that php script on unix system.

Comment: I'm also confused when he said "new thread". Each process has a main thread, so I think what he meant is that each request creates a "new main thread" hence which creates a another process.

Comment: When exactly is PHP process started? After web server gets full request body or right at the start of the transfer?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to chain the web server with PHP.

For `Apache HTTP Server`, the most popular is "mod_php". This module is actually PHP itself, but compiled as a module for the web server, and so it gets loaded right inside it. Since with mod_php, PHP gets loaded right into Apache, if Apache is going to handle concurrency using its Worker MPM (that is, using Threads)

And here is a trap for things like `setlocale()`.

With `Nginx` you won't have the option to embed PHP into it. Hence, PHP is totally outside of the web server with multiple PHP `processes`.

And it is good, because PHP can do things on lower lever, like changing `locales`
And `setlocale()` is NOT thread-safe.