# money_format() not showing currency

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `money_format` function.

```
<?php

$number = 1299.46;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number); // Outputs 1299.46
```

While it should print $ sign or USD ?

I'm on linux hosting.

Thanks

Comment: I can't replicate the issue you are having. Tested 5.6.2 - 4.4.9 all have USD. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e8c4ba1962be5ed422a177e35e6762281b8eda3

Comment: when i used 'en_US.UTF-8' it prints USD

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`money_format` will not work properly if locale is not valid.

For example, on Debian, 'en_US' is not a valid locale - you need 'en_US.UTF-8' or 'en_US.ISO-8559-1'.

Comment: Damn it worked ! I don't understand why people above are marking my question negative.

Comment: Seems they did not understand the question :) Anyway good to hear it is working

Comment: I ran into this issue with a shared server at Network Solutions and the problem is they don't support locale at all on their shared servers. Luckily in my case I was just dealing with US currency so I used `number_format()` instead and just prepended the '$'. Like this: `$result = '$' . number_format(120000);` which returns: $120,000.

Answer (score 5):

Locales are constants defined by the operation system.

I use `Ubuntu` for the following example.

1. check which locales are supported:

   ```
   locale -a
   ```
2. add the locales you want (for example `ru`):

   ```
   sudo locale-gen ru_RU
   sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
   ```
3. run this update comand

   ```
   sudo update-locale
   ```
4. restart php fpm ( check your php version service name like so`service --status-all`)

   ```
   sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
   ```

But be careful, because most likely you are useing `Apache` with "mod_php" because it is the most popular one. And this one works in multi thread environment, when setlocale() is not thread safe. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56676918/2005680) for details

Answer (score 1):

**First you must know php version is using**

> If you are unsure how to check create a file called **info.php**
>
> Insert code =>
>   `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

```
(PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5)
$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56

// Italian national format with 2 decimals`
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo money_format('%.2n', $number) . "\n";
// Eu 1.234,56
```

> Note: The function money_format() is only defined if the system has
>   strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format()
>   is undefined in Windows.

**You can use an alternative
(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PECL intl >= 1.0.0)**

Example #1 numfmt_format_currency() example

```
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo numfmt_format_currency($fmt, 1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo numfmt_format_currency($fmt, 1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'ru_RU', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo numfmt_format_currency($fmt, 1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo numfmt_format_currency($fmt, 1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
```

Example #2 OO example

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'ru_RU', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
```

The above example will output:

```
1.234.567,89 €
1.234.567,89 RUR
1 234 567,89€
1 234 567,89р.
```

Examples taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php)

> If the alternative is not possible, the solution is to create a method
>   for your needs.
>
> **I hope helped you**

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't give $ or USD back, consult the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php). However you can do the following:

`echo money_format('$%i', $number)`

This will give the expected result but ofcourse it is not a dynamic solution.

Comment: Yes actually i want to obtain some dynamic solution. For example a user comes from UK so he should se EUR instead of USD. I thought `setlocate` would handle this thing.

Comment: You should add the dynamic requirement to the question.

Comment: from php.net i was trying: money_format('%(#10n', $Admin_amt); their site implied directly that a $ sign would appear. it did not. your example helped me think to put the $ before the %, and it works. thank you! php.net literally shows[i rearranged a little, to fit here; but see how it shows $ will appear: 

// Using a negative number, $number = -1234.5672;
// US national format, using () for neg numbers and 10 digits for left precision
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%(#10n', $number) . "\n";
// ($        1,234.57)