# Convert array of `YYYMMDD` date strings to a delimited string of days grouped by month

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, grouping, date-formatting

PHP Dates are wonderful things `+1 year` for example. However I'm getting myself in a bit of a mess. I have three dates spanning two months and I want to make an elegant string
"28, 29 February & 1 March" from an array of 3 dates in the form `YYYYMMDD`. The exact number of dates is not known, minimum 1 probable max 4

Other than some rather tortuous `str_replace` manipulation, how do I get from the output of this to my desired format?

NB: no more than 2 months, maybe all in one month.

```
$dates_array = ['20240228', '20240229', '20240301'];

foreach ($dates_array as $date) :
  $datetimes[]  = new DateTime($date);
endforeach;

// print_r($datetimes);

foreach ($datetimes as $key=>$date) :
  $month = $date->format('F');
  $day = $date->format('j');                                    
  $date_array[]= $day." ".$month." & ";
endforeach;

$date_string =  join( ' ', $date_array ) ;

echo $date_string;

// 28 February & 29 February & 1 March &
```

Comment: Are those dates guaranteed to be contiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create this:

```
$dates = ['20240228', '20240229', '20240301'];

function formatDates(array $datesInput) {
    foreach ($datesInput as $datesKey => $date) {
        $date  = new DateTime($date);
        $month = $date->format('F');
        $day   = $date->format('j');
        if ($datesKey == 0) {
            $datesOutput = $day;
        } elseif ($currentMonth <> $month) {
            $datesOutput .= " $currentMonth & $day";
        } else {
            $datesOutput .= ", $day";
        }
        $currentMonth = $month;
    }
    return "$datesOutput $month";
}

echo formatDates($dates);
```

This returns:

```
28, 29 February & 1 March
```

It is not all that complicated. I did however put everything in a function because I would otherwise have to create quite a few global variables, and that's [seen as bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124793/php-why-global-variables-are-evil).

For a demo see: https://3v4l.org/gUWih

Comment: I think this illustrates why I got tangled, by thinking of the output whilst iterating the dates is more logical.

Answer (score 2):

One more possible way to approach this, grouping the dates by month in an array first, and joining it all together with `implode`:

```
$dates_array = ['20240228', '20240229', '20240301'];

foreach ($dates_array as $date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $datesByMonth[$date->format('F')][] = $date->format('j');
}

foreach($datesByMonth as $month => $dates) {
    $datesByMonth[$month] = implode(', ', $dates) . ' ' . $month;
}

echo implode(' & ', $datesByMonth);
```

https://3v4l.org/6snHe

Obviously won't work if you had dates for the same month *in different years*, but I guess that's not a requirement(?).

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach. No, the question never talks about years, so I ignored that as well.

Comment: I think you could combine your first two `foreach` loops into one and you don't use the `$key` in the second loop. Like this: https://3v4l.org/YhFOi

Comment: @KIKOSoftware sure, first one was just a "leftover" from the original code, and the $key was used in a first version I had, that was slightly different.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware replaced the code in the answer with your reduced version. I really like to use `implode` for stuff like this, because it removes the need to perform any checks on the number of items, regarding whether a separator needs to be inserted or not.

Answer (score 1):

As you loop through the `$datetimes` you'd have to check whether the next value in the list is in the same month or not, in order to know whether to include the month name in the formatted output for that date or not.

This is one way to do that. The broad assumption is that the dates will always be supplied in ascending order, but it does also check if the next date is in the same year, as well as the same month, in case there's a large gap between dates.

```
$dates_array = ['20241203', '20240115', '20240116', '20240228', '20240229', '20240301'];

foreach ($dates_array as $date)
{
  $datetimes[]  = new DateTime($date);
}

foreach ($datetimes as $key=>$date) 
{
  $dateStr = $date->format('j');
  
  //check if there's another entry after this one
  if (isset($datetimes[$key+1]))
  {
      //check the if following entry is in the same month and year as this one
      if ($datetimes[$key+1]->format("ym") == $date->format("ym")) {
          $dateStr .= ",";
      }
      else
      {
          $dateStr .= " ".$date->format("F")." & ";
      }
  }
  else {
      $dateStr .= " ".$date->format("F");
  }
  
  $date_array[]= $dateStr;
}

$date_string =  join( ' ', $date_array ) ;

echo $date_string;
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/tWrhe

Answer (score 1):

Here is another stab at this:

Iterate over the dates, in each iteration check if previous date is contiguous and belongs to same month.

```
<?php
$dates_array = ["20240214", "20240228", "20240229", "20240301"];

$datetime_array = array_map(function($date_string) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd", $date_string);
}, $dates_array);

$groups = array_reduce($datetime_array, function($groups, $curr) {
    $key1 = array_key_last($groups);
    if ($key1 === null) {
        $key1 = 0;
    } else {
        $key2 = array_key_last($groups[$key1]);
        $prev = $groups[$key1][$key2];
        if ($prev->diff($curr)->d !== 1 || $prev->format("n") !== $curr->format("n")) {
            $key1 += 1;
        }
    }
    $groups[$key1][] = $curr;
    return $groups;
}, []);

$result = array_map(function($group) {
    $key1 = array_key_last($group);
    return $key1 === 0 ? $group[$key1]->format("j F") : ($group[0]->format("j") . "-" . $group[$key1]->format("j F"));
}, $groups);

echo implode(", ", $result);

// 14 February, 28-29 February, 1 March
```

Answer (score 1):

I find CBroe's script to be very lean and readable, I might write it this way:

I might use `array_map()` for the second looping task so that data can be conveniently `implode()`ed twice.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jhnut))

```
$dates = ['20240228', '20240229', '20240301'];

$groups = [];
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $groups[$date->format('F')][] = $date->format('j');
}

echo implode(
         ' & ',
         array_map(
             fn($j, $F) => implode(', ', $j) . " $F",
             $groups,
             array_keys($groups)
         )
     );

/* or
echo implode(
         ' & ',
         array_reduce(
             array_keys($groups),
             fn($result, $k) => $result + [$k => implode(', ', $groups[$k]) . " $k"],
             []
         )
     );
*/
```

---

As for a string-builder script like KIKO's, my script will either append text to the end when a new month is encountered, or inject a new "last day" for a re-encountered month.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ar5ji))

```
$dates = ['20240228', '20240229', '20240301'];

$text = '';
foreach ($dates as $i => $date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $month = $date->format('F');
    $day = $date->format('j');
    $pos = strpos($text, $month);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $text = substr_replace($text, ", $day", $pos - 1, 0);
    } else {
        $text .= ($text ? ' & ' : '') . "$day $month";
    }
}

echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this small script, I advise you to make a nice test to be sure it works with different use cases.

```
<?php
$dates = ['20240228', '20240229','20240301'];
$countDates = count($dates) - 1;
$output = [];

foreach ($dates as $date) :
  $datetimes[]  = new DateTime($date);
endforeach;

foreach ($datetimes as $i => $datetime) :
  $dateOutput = [$datetime->format('j')];
  $isNextMonthTheSame = isset($datetimes[$i+1]) && $datetime->format('m') === $datetimes[$i+1]->format('m');
  if (!$isNextMonthTheSame) {
    $dateOutput []= ' '. $datetime->format('F');  
    $dateOutput []= ' & ';
  } else {
    $dateOutput []= ', ';
  }
  if ($i === $countDates) {
    array_pop($dateOutput);
  }
  $output []= $dateOutput;
endforeach;

echo implode(array_merge(...$output));
```

PS: the spread operator (`...`) has been implemented in PHP 7.4: